# Adjust List of Figures or Tables in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2007

I created a List of Figures in Word based on the caption. My caption is something like:

```
Figure 1-Name of figure.
```

The list of figures created in Word look like below: (after adjusting the hanging indent)

[image]

How you change the layout similar to something like this in Word?

[image]

As you can see that, only figure number is displayed and the page number is tidily displayed separately. Also the layout for the figure caption is justified.

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but requires some work.

1. Add tab after „Figure X” in all captions (and set its position according to your needs).
2. Change style used for list of figures:

   - set 2 tab stops: first e.g. 3 cm with left alignment, second – e.g. 16 cm to the right (with dots leader)
   - change paragraph settings in style: set right indentation (e.g. 2 cm) and in Special set Hanging to the same value as left tab stop position (e.g. 3 cm).

Screenshot is taken with cursor placed in the List of Figures so you can see example settings on the ruler.

[image: List of figures with ruler]

Answer (score 0):

*endrju* has explained how to configure the Table of Figures paragraph style to get the alignment that you want. If you want to include the word 'Figure' in the caption itself and put an em dash between the figure number and title, but omit 'Figure' in the Table of figures and replace the dash with a tab, you need to use field codes. Here's how I did it. (For this, you wouldn't follow step 1 of *endrju*'s explanation.):

1. Make paragraph marks visible if they aren't (on the **Home** tab, in the **Paragraph** group, click **¶**).
2. In one of the caption paragraphs, select the title text (e.g., 'Pictorial view...x<sub>2</sub>.' in your example). On the **Insert** tab, in the **Links** group, click **Bookmark**, and add a bookmark.
3. Place the cursor at the end of the caption paragraph, and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (that's the letter O, not a zero). In the dialog box, enter some dummy text (at least one character) in the **Entry** field, and select **F** in the **Table identifier** field. Click **OK**.
4. Inside the braces ({}) for the `TC` field, the dummy text that you entered will be enclosed in quotation marks. Select the text (but not the quotation marks), and then, on the **Insert** tab, in the **Text** group, click **Explore Quick Parts** > **Field**. In the **Field names** list, select **Seq**. In the **Field codes** field, after `SEQ`, type a space, and then type `Figure \* Arabic \c`. Click **OK**. This will pull in the auto-generated caption number.
5. The cursor should be between the field that you just inserted and the closing quotation mark. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, since you want the figure number and title to be separated by a tab space in your Table of figures.
6. On the **Insert** tab, in the **Text** group, click **Explore Quick Parts** > **Field**. In the **Field names** list, select **Ref**, and then, in the **Bookmark name** list, select the bookmark that you inserted earlier. This will pull in the figure title text that you bookmarked earlier.
   You should end up with something like this:
   [image: Figure, caption, and completed TC field]
   Here's what the caption looks like if I toggle field codes:
   [image: The same when field codes are toggled]
   And here's what it will look like in the published document, or if I hide paragraph marks:
   [image: Finished caption]
7. Repeat steps 2 through 6 for every figure in your document.
8. Position the cursor where you want the Table of figures to appear. On the **References** tab, in the **Captions** group, click **Insert Table of Figures**. In the dialog box, in the **Caption label** field, select **(none)**, and then click **Options**. Make sure that the **Style** check box is cleared. Select the **Table entry fields** check box, and make sure that **F** is selected in the **Table identifier** field. Click **OK** twice.
   **Note:** In order to get the dots leaders to show up between the figure title and page number, I had to set them up on the tab stop that's defined for the Table of Figures paragraph style. Selecting a value in the **Tab leader** field in the **Table of Figures** dialog box didn't have any effect.

Here's the completed Table of figures for my document:
[image: Table of figures]

Comment: Hi,

Is Step 7 should be done for all figures in the document? Is there any way for automatic update as the number of figures is huge, i.e. hundreds in the document?

Comment: Also, as you can see the figure is numbered based on the Chapter.FigureNumber format, i.e. Figure 1.1 represents figure 1 in chapter 1, or Figure 2.1 represents figure 1 in chapter 2. How you do the list of tables for this case as the example you showed only for figure number without including the chapter number.

Comment: @JcoHut, Yes, you have to do steps 2-6 (i.e., step 7) for every figure, as I note in my answer. You may be able to write code that does this, but that's outside my skill set. For the chapter number, I don't have Word available right now, but I believe you can just copy that part of the auto-generated figure number and paste it into the TC field, right before the SEQ field and followed by whatever character you want to use as a separator (a period, in your example). Or add a STYLEREF field to get the number of the nearest preceding Heading 1 paragraph – for example, { STYLEREF "Heading 1" \n }

Comment: Hi @cnread, thank you for the effort offering this solution. I ended up with manual adjustment playing with tabs and paragraph setting in Word as it requires less time and efforts significantly. I can share it if any of user here have the same problem.

Comment: @cnread Hi, I would greatly appreciate if you could let me know how to solve this issue when the list of figures are created using ''custom table of content''.